# Disabling AVX at Android NDK

Tags: android, testing, gcc, toolchain

I have trouble with passing GCC test (test_installed) - receiving errors at AVX test:

> error: incompatible type for argument 2 of '_mm_maskstore_pd'
>   avxintrin.h:900 note: expected '_*m128d' but argument is of type '*_m128i'

How can I disable AVX test, or pass it?

Comment: it's standart gcc 4.4.6 sources and Android NDK.
http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/gcc/testsuite/gcc.target/i386/avx-vmaskmovpd-1.c
http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/i386/avxintrin.h

Comment: What you are showing is file for x86 target. Is your target platform x86-based? Also, please post your NDK version.

Comment: Yes x86 based platform, NDK r8 for linux.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I found answer.
All i must to do it's apply [this patch](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2010-07/msg01791.html) to change test file for correct determining of supporting AVX.